# About resizing an array (simple Java)

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, queue

Here's textbook implementation of resizing method in Algorithms 4th edition for ResizingArrayQueue ADT:

```
private void resize(int capacity) {
    assert capacity >= n;
    Item[] temp = (Item[]) new Object[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp[i] = q[(first + i) % q.length];
    }
    q = temp;
    first = 0;
    last  = n;
}
```

My question is why bother using `(first + i) % q.length` as index when copy `q` to `temp`? Shouldn't it always equal to `first + i`? What is the mod for?

Full code https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/ResizingArrayQueue.java.html

Comment: I don't see where `first` is being declared/defined.

Comment: if temp is larger, you need the q to not got out of bounds. This would keep copying the list elements in a circular fashion

Comment: This is not resizing an array.  It is resizing an array **queue**.  If you look at the other methods, you will see that the queue wraps around the end of the array and back to the beginning.  This is a classical "circular buffer" arrangement.

Comment: So the answer to your question: *"Shouldn't it always equal to first + i?"* is a resounding No.  Look at the code again.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - `q`, `first` and `last` are instance variables .... of the queue class.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you.Now I understand it's because the circular thingy.